# jquery .find(), getting multiple unwanted information

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to parse the id:`1` out of this XML:

```
-<data>
 -<group>
   <id>1</id>
   <isFolder>true</isFolder>
   -<condition>
      <id>2</id>
    </condition>
   -<conditionCounts>
      <id>3</id>
    <conditionCounts>
  </group>
 </data>
```

I am using jquery, $br is already set.

```
 groupId= $br.find('group').find('id');
```

This gives me `groupId = 123`, it gives me all the id's inside `<group>`. I only want the first id, which is `1`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**.first()**](http://api.jquery.com/first/), The method returns the first element of the selected elements.

```
groupId= $br.find('group').find('id').first();
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. Will accept this answer when time's up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the `id` element that is a/the **child** of the `group` element (not a general descendant). In that case, use `.children`:

```
$br.find('group').children('id')
```